# Why when I changed the value of the variable using pointer, the value was still the same?

Tags: c++

can someone explain why the output of `firstvalue` is 10 although it is manipulated at the end when writing `*p=20`?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main(){

    int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
    int * p1, * p2;
    p1 = &firstvalue; 
    p2 = &secondvalue; 
    *p1 = 10; 
    *p2 = *p1; 
    p1 = p2; 
    *p1 = 20; 
     
    cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << endl;
    cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << endl;
    cout << "p1 is " << p1 << endl;
    cout << "p2 is " << p2 << endl;
    cout << "*p1 is " << *p1 << endl;
    cout << "*p2 is " << *p2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Output:

```
firstvalue is 10
secondvalue is 20
p1 is 0x7ffc0589c4f4
p2 is 0x7ffc0589c4f4
*p1 is 20
*p2 is 20
```

Comment: Think about what `p1 = p2;` does in the line right before it

Comment: The output of the pointers `p1` and `p2` should make it kind of obvious.

Comment: Well, `p1` no longer points to `firstvalue`.

Comment: Indent your code. Writingyourcodewithoutindentationislikewritingebglishwithoutspacesabdpunctuationitouldbereadbutitisnotapleasantexperiencefrmostpeople.

Comment: Put in more output statements, and look at the relevant values after **each change**. Or run the code in a debugger so you can look at the values as you go along.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, your answers helped in other codes as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a more "graphical" illustration might help you understand what's happening?

After the assignments

```
p1 = &firstvalue;
p2 = &secondvalue;
```

you have something which looks like this:

```
+----+     +------------+
| p1 | --> | firstvalue |
+----+     +------------+

+----+     +-------------+
| p2 | --> | secondvalue |
+----+     +-------------+
```

So when you dereference `p1` then you get the value of `firstvalue`.

But you change things with the assignment

```
p1 = p2;
```

That makes `p1` point to the same thing that `p2` is pointing to, and you now have:

```
+----+
| p1 | --\
+----+    \     +-------------+
           >--> | secondvalue |
+----+    /     +-------------+
| p2 | --/
+----+
```

Now dereferencing `p1` will give you the value of `secondvalue` instead.

---

In the future when you have problems with pointers, I suggest you take out a pencil and some paper and draw everything yourself.

Draw boxes for "things", like variables etc. Then draw arrows for pointers, from the pointer box to the thing they point to.

Then when changing a pointer, you erase the arrow and draw a new one.

Comment: "Draw your stuff on paper" is the most best advice about anything pointer-related. I suspect that many beginners believe that if you're any good at all you shouldn't need it, but all the best programmers I've met do it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

> why the output of firstvalue is 10 although it is manipulated at the end when writing *p=20?

There is no `*p=20` in the program.

There is `*p1 = 20` which doesn't manipulate `firstvalue` because `p1` doesn't point to `firstvalue`. It points to `secondvalue` because of this assignment: `p1 = p2`.

Answer (score 1):

With these istructions:

```
p1 = &firstvalue; 
p2 = &secondvalue;
```

`p1` points to `firstvalue`, and `p2` to `secondvalue`.

The next two instructions:

```
*p1 = 10; 
*p2 = *p1;
```

set the value pointed by `p1` to 10, i.e., `firstvalue` is set to 10, and the value pointed by `p2` (`secondvalue`) to the value pointed by `p1`. So now `firstvalue = secondvalue = 10`.

This istruction:

```
p1 = p2;
```

set the pointer `p1` to `p2`: now `p1` points to `secondvalue`. After that, this istruction

```
*p1 = 20
```

set the value of `secondvalue` to 20, while `firstvalue` is untouched.